# How can I filter values based on other columns?

Tags: database, filter, vega-lite, vega

How can I select certain values and/or values conditional on other columns in vega-lite? For example, below I only want to show values that have "*red*" in the column "*c*".

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 2, "c": "red"}, 
      {"a": "A", "b": 7, "c": "red"}, 
      {"a": "A", "b": 4, "c": "blue"},
      {"a": "B", "b": 1, "c": "blue"}, 
      {"a": "B", "b": 2, "c": "red"} 
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal"},
    "y": {"aggregate": "average", "field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

I have tried adding the following code before `"mark": "bar",` according to [this vega github tutorial](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite-v1/docs/transform.html), and using [the online vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/), but it doesn't filter column *b*. I thought I could use it to somehow filter a string as well.

```
"transform": {
    "filter": "datum.b > 3"
  },
```

---

[Follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68737548/how-can-i-filter-values-with-multiple-conditions) regarding multiple filtering criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a filter transform:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 2, "c": "red"},
      {"a": "A", "b": 7, "c": "red"},
      {"a": "A", "b": 4, "c": "blue"},
      {"a": "B", "b": 1, "c": "blue"},
      {"a": "B", "b": 2, "c": "red"}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [{"filter": "datum.c == 'red'"}],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal"},
    "y": {"aggregate": "average", "field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```