# How can I filter values with multiple conditions?

Tags: json, database, filter, vega-lite, vega

How can I filter values with multiple conditions based on other columns? In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68714466/how-can-i-filter-values-based-on-other-columns/68717947#68717947), the answer shows how to filter with a single condition using `filter transform`:

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 2, "c": "red"},
      {"a": "A", "b": 7, "c": "yellow"},
      {"a": "A", "b": 4, "c": "blue"},
      {"a": "B", "b": 1, "c": "blue"},
      {"a": "B", "b": 2, "c": "red"}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [{"filter": "datum.c == 'red'"}],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal"},
    "y": {"aggregate": "average", "field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

I want to filter all values with "red" and "blue" in the column *c*, so no "yellow". I believe the `OneOf` logical operator needs to be used as shown in the [vega documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/predicate.html#one-of-predicate), but I can't figure out how. I changed the `transform` part to:

```
"transform": [{"field": "c", "oneOf": ["red", "blue"]}],
```

but that doesn't work in the [online vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `filter` transform can be used as string as well as object. While using string type you can give your condition as:

```
"transform": [{"filter": "datum.c == 'red' || datum.c == 'blue'"}],
```

And while using object it can be:

```
"transform": [{"filter": {"field": "c", "oneOf": ["red", "blue"]}}],
```

Depending on the complexity you can use any of the two types. To answer your question refer the below code or refer [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoDSACCikEzQAmJVDQgATnGUgAvgpOOLS66gB2e0cATzhBQTYAdw8vEFNfKzQAFmD0Jl04WO90ACFLfwBGNKtM7PjHfL9bEpc3dwBdTxBMJyRZCAAzNicEI1BOmkFMOCc0AZpwt3QHJTk4AHlOo2dXArKmxqVkJwBrRyYkMaU4WSg2ZRpZMnGQAA9bwanHFCVMEJws9Fk2BCudWIgEK3JBkMguCgjF6kNpkLJKJ6CaZJN4fL4gACODHamDoahopA87ncQA):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 2, "c": "red"},
      {"a": "A", "b": 7, "c": "yellow"},
      {"a": "A", "b": 4, "c": "blue"},
      {"a": "B", "b": 1, "c": "blue"},
      {"a": "B", "b": 2, "c": "red"}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [{"filter": {"field": "c", "oneOf": ["red", "blue"]}}],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal"},
    "y": {"aggregate": "average", "field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```