# Highlighting specific columns in bar chart in python using altair

Tags: python, altair

I want to highlight specific data points in a bar chart in python based on my requirement. using altair, I am able to achieve results for one data point (for e.g 'A' in the code). Here's the sample data frame and code

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Rank': [25, 20, 40, 10, 50, 35],
    'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],   
})


bar1 =alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode( y = alt.Y('Rank'),
                                       x = alt.X('Name:O', sort ='x'),
    color=alt.condition(
        alt.datum.Name == 'A',  
        alt.value('red'),     
        alt.value('blue')     
    ))
bar1
```

[image]

How can I highlight two or more datapoints (eg. A & B) with the same color and others with a different one? I tried passing the names as a list  `Select = ['A', 'B']`  and then passing the `alt.datum.Name == Select` but that does not work?

How can i get this done?
Also, trying to understand why passing as a list did not work?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `FieldOneOfPredicate` to check if the `Name` column is *one of* the items in the list:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Rank': [25, 20, 40, 10, 50, 35],
    'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],   
})


bar1 =alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode( y = alt.Y('Rank'),
                                       x = alt.X('Name:O', sort ='x'),
    color=alt.condition(
        alt.FieldOneOfPredicate('Name', ['A', 'B']),
        alt.value('red'),     
        alt.value('blue')     
    ))
bar1
```

[image]

You can read more about it in [the VegaLite docs](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/predicate.html#one-of-predicate). You could also use two expression string with an "or" operator:

```
color=alt.condition(
    "datum.Name == 'A'"
    "|| datum.Name == 'B'",  # splitting on two rows for readability
    alt.value('red'),     
    alt.value('blue')     
)
```

I don't think there is a single Vega expression operator that you can use for checking membership like Python's `in`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68737548/how-can-i-filter-values-with-multiple-conditions) doesn't mention it either.